# Rotating a face of a rubiks cube

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, transpose

I have a Face class which takes in the 3x3 integer array for each individual side of a rubiks cube. I am trying to create a rotateRight() method whereby

```
010203                 070401
040506     becomes     080502
070809                 090603
```

However, I am unsure how to make my method rotateRight() return a type Face (which is the current error I am facing when I run my code). May I get some help with this? Below is the code I currently have:

```
public class Face{
  private int[][] grid;

  public Face(int[][] grid){
    grid = new int[3][3];
  }


  public Face rotateRight(){
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 3;
    int[][] transposedArray = new int[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j<cols; j++){
        transposedArray[j][i]=grid[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is Rotate method supposed to change an existing Face or produce a new one?

Comment: what are the errors. Can you post the errors too?

Comment: Note that that would probably be a `rotateFront` method in Cubing lingo.

Comment: @PM77-1it is supposed to return a new one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new `Face` instance to return, but you also need to adapt your array assignment in the loop. Otherwise you won't assign the correct positions.

```
public Face rotateRight(){
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 3;
    int[][] transposedArray = new int[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<cols; j++){
            transposedArray[j][2-i]=grid[i][j];
        }
    }
    return new Face(transposedArray);
}
```

I have taken the liberty to slightly adapt your code, to allow the front rotation on cubes of 3x3, 4x4, 5x5, ...
and in both directions

Here is a class with helper methods to demonstrate the usage:

```
public class Face{
    private int[][] grid;

    public Face(int[][] grid){
        this.grid = grid;
    }

    enum DIRECTION {
        RIGHT,
        LEFT
    }

    public Face rotateFront(DIRECTION direction){
        int rows = grid.length;
        int[][] transposedArray = new int[rows][rows];

        for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j<rows; j++){
                if (direction == DIRECTION.RIGHT) {
                    transposedArray[j][(rows-1)-i]=grid[i][j];
                } else {
                    transposedArray[(rows-1)-j][i]=grid[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        return new Face(transposedArray);
    }

    public String toString() {
        int rows = grid.length;
        String output = "";
        for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j<rows; j++){
                output += "["+ grid[i][j]+"] ";
            }
            output += "\n";
        }
        return output;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] originalArray = new int[][]{ { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 }};

        System.out.println("Create our inital Face:");
        Face startFace = new Face(originalArray);
        System.out.println(startFace);

        System.out.println("Rotate our inital Face to the right:");
        Face rotatedFace = startFace.rotateFront(DIRECTION.RIGHT);
        System.out.println(rotatedFace);

        System.out.println("Rotate our rotated Face to the left:");
        Face rotatedFace2 = rotatedFace.rotateFront(DIRECTION.LEFT);
        System.out.println(rotatedFace2);
    }
}
```

This outputs:

> Create our inital Face:
>   [1] [2] [3]
>   [4] [5] [6]
>   [7] [8] [9]
>
> Rotate our inital Face to the right:
>   [7] [4] [1]
>   [8] [5] [2]
>   [9] [6] [3]
>
> Rotate our rotated Face to the left:
>   [1] [2] [3]
>   [4] [5] [6]
>   [7] [8] [9]

I hope this helps you continue your Rubiks cube development.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right you fail because you do not return a Face type at the end of your method. If that is right you just have to create a new `Face` instance at `rotateRight()`:

```
public Face rotateRight(){
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 3;
    int[][] transposedArray = new int[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j<cols; j++){
        transposedArray[j][i]=grid[i][j];
      }
    }
    return new Face(transposedArray)
  }
```